# Boosting ggplot2 performance

Tags: r, performance, ggplot2

The `ggplot2` package is easily the best plotting system I ever worked with, except that the performance is not really good for larger datasets (~50k points). I'm looking into providing web analyses through Shiny, using `ggplot2` as the plotting backend, but I'm not really happy with the performance, especially in contrast with base graphics. My question is if there any concrete ways to increase this performance.

The starting point is the following code example:

```
library(ggplot2)

n = 86400 # a day in seconds
dat = data.frame(id = 1:n, val = sort(runif(n)))

dev.new()

gg_base = ggplot(dat, aes(x = id, y = val))
gg_point = gg_base + geom_point()
gg_line = gg_base + geom_line()
gg_both = gg_base + geom_point() + geom_line()

benchplot(gg_point)
benchplot(gg_line)
benchplot(gg_both)
system.time(plot(dat))
system.time(plot(dat, type = 'l'))
```

I get the following timings on my MacPro retina:

```
> benchplot(gg_point)
       step user.self sys.self elapsed
1 construct     0.000    0.000   0.000
2     build     0.321    0.078   0.398
3    render     0.271    0.088   0.359
4      draw     2.013    0.018   2.218
5     TOTAL     2.605    0.184   2.975
> benchplot(gg_line)
       step user.self sys.self elapsed
1 construct     0.000    0.000   0.000
2     build     0.330    0.073   0.403
3    render     0.622    0.095   0.717
4      draw     2.078    0.009   2.266
5     TOTAL     3.030    0.177   3.386
> benchplot(gg_both)
       step user.self sys.self elapsed
1 construct     0.000    0.000   0.000
2     build     0.602    0.155   0.757
3    render     0.866    0.186   1.051
4      draw     4.020    0.030   4.238
5     TOTAL     5.488    0.371   6.046
> system.time(plot(dat))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.133   0.004   1.138 
# Note that the timing below depended heavily on wether or net the graphics device
# was in view or not. Not in view made performance much, much better.
> system.time(plot(dat, type = 'l'))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.230   0.003   1.233
```

Some more info on my setup:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.9.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] MASS_7.3-23        RColorBrewer_1.0-5 colorspace_1.2-1   dichromat_2.0-0   
 [5] digest_0.6.3       grid_2.15.3        gtable_0.1.2       labeling_0.1      
 [9] munsell_0.4        plyr_1.8           proto_0.3-10       reshape2_1.2.2    
[13] scales_0.2.3       stringr_0.6.2
```

Comment: Would distributing (separate) plots over multiple cores or caching meet your needs?

Comment: Anything that speeds up plotting is acceptable, caching is not really a solution as this question deals with the situation that the user actually needs a new plot to be drawn (axis changed, color of a line, etc).

Comment: ggplot2 has a built-in timing system, `benchplot()`, to help identify why it's so slow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hadley had a cool [talk](http://www.edii.uclm.es/~useR-2013/invited/useR2013_wickham.pdf) about his new packages [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr) and [ggvis](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis) at user2013. But he can probably better tell more about that himself.

I'm not sure what your application design looks like, but I often do in-database pre-processing before feeding the data to R. For example, if you are plotting time series, there is really no need to show every second of the day on the X axis. Instead you might want to aggregate and get the min/max/mean over e.g. one or five minute time intervals.

Below an example of a function I wrote years ago that did something like that in SQL. This particular example uses the modulo operator because times were stored as epoch millis. But if data in SQL are properly stored as date/datetime structures, SQL has some more elegant native methods to aggregate by time periods.

```
#' @param table name of the table
#' @param start start time/date
#' @param end end time/date
#' @param aggregate one of "days", "hours", "mins" or "weeks"
#' @param group grouping variable
#' @param column name of the target column (y axis)
#' @export
minmaxdata <- function(table, start, end, aggregate=c("days", "hours", "mins", "weeks"), group=1, column){

  #dates
  start <- round(unclass(as.POSIXct(start))*1000);
  end <- round(unclass(as.POSIXct(end))*1000);

  #must aggregate
  aggregate <- match.arg(aggregate);

  #calcluate modulus
  mod <- switch(aggregate,
    "mins"   = 1000*60,
    "hours"  = 1000*60*60,
    "days"   = 1000*60*60*24,
    "weeks"  = 1000*60*60*24*7,
    stop("invalid aggregate value")
  );

  #we need to add the time differene between gmt and pst to make modulo work
  delta <- 1000 * 60 * 60 * (24 - unclass(as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time(), tz="GMT")) - Sys.time()));  

  #form query
  query <- paste("SELECT", group, "AS grouping, AVG(", column, ") AS yavg, MAX(", column, ") AS ymax, MIN(", column, ") AS ymin, ((CMilliseconds_g +", delta, ") DIV", mod, ") AS timediv FROM", table, "WHERE CMilliseconds_g BETWEEN", start, "AND", end, "GROUP BY", group, ", timediv;")
  mydata <- getquery(query);

  #data
  mydata$time <- structure(mod*mydata[["timediv"]]/1000 - delta/1000, class=c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"));
  mydata$grouping <- as.factor(mydata$grouping)

  #round timestamps
  if(aggregate %in% c("mins", "hours")){
    mydata$time <- round(mydata$time, aggregate)
  } else {
    mydata$time <- as.Date(mydata$time);
  }

  #return
  return(mydata)
}
```

Comment: +1! I agree that aggregation is a good option, which is definitely worth exploring. I'm however not sure if the client (scientists) are going to be happy with this kind of smoothing that is purely for performance.

Comment: It's not just about performance. The eye simply can't read 86400 points on an axis and your monitor doesn't have the resolution to show it. If you want to viz big(ish) data you will always have to do some aggregation, or your plot will become a mess.

Comment: I agree, but in this example we only draw one line. Let's say the ~100k points are distributed over several facet's, and a smoothing is added. In this way you can quite easily get a good plot, that still needs to draw lot's of data.