# Speeding up ggplot2: does it make sense to pre-render plots?

Tags: r, performance, plot, ggplot2, rendering

I am building an interactive function that will repeatedly build and plot reasonably complicated `ggplot2` plots.

Users provide input (rotation angles for a PCA loadings matrix, actually), and I'd like to show them rotated results asap.

Unfortunately, plotting the plots with ggplot2 is quite sluggish.

Note:

- There is emphatically *not* a lot of data (<100 data points or so), so pre-processing won't help (that's the issue on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352426/boosting-ggplot2-performance) and a lot of other SO ggplot2 performance posts).
- I have to stick with ggplot2 for now. (I know, I know, `ggobi` etc. ...).
- I *do* know the *range* of possible inputs in advance (0-360): that's a very finite number.
- I *have* cached the ggplot-generating functions with `memoise`, but that doesn't seem to help much; the problem seems to be the actual plotting on the graphics device.
- (I also noticed that the internal graphics device of RStudio is particularly sluggish).

So, I thought, maybe I'd be an idea to somehow **pre-render** all necessary plots, maybe by saving the `svg()` graphics device to a file or something, and then to plot those cached versions as necessary.

- On a scale of 1-10, how stupid of an idea is that?
- Any better ideas?
- Will this even speed up the plotting, or will the graphics device still be the bottleneck?
- Why can't we have hardware acceleration in R :(.

---

**Update**

- this is not hosted software (for now), just working locally and it should work from any number of clients and on any number of platforms.
- I am aware of (the much faster) `ggvis` and `ggobi`, but these are for now not an option (development bandwidth is too small).
- There are actually several, relatively complicated, nested (`grid.arrange`d) plotting functions, and those were `memoise`d at some point – with no noticeable speed increase.
- Opening pre-rendered files in an external file viewer seems to endanger cross-platform appeal – correct?

Comment: Where is this hosted? Are you using shiny? If not, do you envision your end-user using RStudio? You mention ggobi, but have you considered `ggvis`? You say you've cached ggplot-generating functions, did you really have many functions that do plotting---I would have assumed you have a single plotting function.

Comment: Sure you can save all the plots as files. It won't speed up re-plotting them, but you could just write a function that shows the pre-saved images instead, or use your favorite image viewer which would be almost no work and super fast.